Translation of "off" in a weird context
Informally in English you can add off at the end of words or phrases to imply a competition which I guess comes from the word "playoff". For example, "dance-off" or "speech-off" would mean a dance competition and a who-can-do-the-best-speech competition respectively. I was just wondering if there was a way in French I could translate this use of "off" rather than a basic translation that doesn't convey its informal nature such as just « un concours de danse/discours ».
Thanks for any guidance :)

Playoff typically translates to finale, demi-finale, départage, s/times to tiebreak (yes, it's a French word) depending on the specific activity. "Une finale de danse" is pretty informal. Could you add examples where informality is of the essence?

The off as competition or game does not really work with speech, except as a nonce usage and some other examples. But what's wrong with concours for the dance example? It would be quite odd for a usage like this to have some correspondence in another language that in that language would work the same way. Phrasal verbs are typical in English, but not in other languages.

Yeah there's not really anything similar. The best you can do is paraphrase in English (bake-off -> baking contest) and then translate that. Same for out+, like "outrun", "outperform" etc., that can be jokingly used with basically any verb (or even non-verbs: outdance, outstupid, ...). We don't have anything similar in French so you have to resort to a long sentence like "he danced better than me".

What is called playoff in English might be called match(s) de barrage or just barrage(s) in French, at least when traditional sports are involved and especially when the objective is to select a winner that will be promoted in an upper division/league.
TLFi Barrage


SP. Match de barrage. Match servant à départager deux concurrents ou deux équipes qui, au cours d'une compétition générale (championnat, coupe, etc.), sont à égalité de points.


Also: Barrages de la coupe du monde 2022
Wikipedia English Football >League System

English Football League Championship (level 2, 24 teams): Top two automatically promoted; next four compete in the play-offs, with the winner gaining the third promotion spot. The bottom three are relegated.

For several competitions, there are also two phases, the first one is called phase de poules or les qualifs and the second one the phase éliminatoire or phase finale up to the actual finale. This second phase composed of knock-out games might also match what 'playoffs' means too. The semi-finals level is often called le dernier carré, with four teams or individuals still competing.
Many competitions ending with éliminatoires (playoffs) are called coupes as opposed to championnats where a draw is possible between two teams.
When in France we talk about the NFL (very rare) or the NBA (a little bit more, especially when a Frenchman is involved), we keep the English term playoffs. NHL or MLB are essentially unknown in France.
That's different in Québec where série éliminatoire, the recommended translation, is used.
Barrage wouldn't really apply to danse or speech competitions, tours éliminatoires or épreuves éliminatoires might.
Playoffs doesn't necessarily mean direct elimination though, for example round-robin playoffs do not. The single thing all kinds of playoffs have in common is that there must be a single winner.
Anyway, a danse competition might just be called un concours de danse. There is no register issues with this expression as it works whatever the context.

If you really look for an informal tone, you might say une compèt' de [...].

The concours de discours that you suggested doesn't really work1. What we would say here is concours d'éloquence. Here again, compèt' d'éloquence could work but the informal compèt' kind of defeats the éloquence part...


1 Along speech-off, speak-off has several occurrences on the web like that one or the following one.

Similar usage:




Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
